# Performance issue with Activiti query

Tags: activiti

I am querying for a task to claim on basis of candidate user group and priority but it takes around 8 to 10 second find below the query used

```
taskService.createTaskQuery().taskCandidateGroupIn('CG1','CG2').orderByTaskPriority().desc().listPage(0, 10);
```

Am i doing it in the right way? Please advice

Comment: are you claiming multiple tasks at once?

Comment: I am querying for 10 task and will claim one of them